# How do I do a reverse to_i?

Tags: ruby, string, parsing, integer

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  If there are numbers at the beginning of my string, I can get the value as an integer by doing

```
2.4.0 :003 >   s = "13s"
 => "13s"
2.4.0 :004 > s.to_i
 => 13
```

However, how do I get the numbers as an integer if they are at the end of my string?  For instance, in

```
s13
```

I have "13" at the end of the string, but obviously, .to_i won't extract that ...

```
2.4.0 :005 > s = "s13"
 => "s13"
2.4.0 :006 > s.to_i
 => 0
```

What's a generic way of extracting the numerical portion of the end of a string?  IF the string is

```
abcd
```

I'd expect the numerical portion to just be zero.

Comment: Digits at the beginning of your string, not numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be this one

```
"s13".reverse.to_i.to_s.reverse
```

Or extract the digits from the end of the string

```
"s13"[/\d+\z/]
```

Comment: why not just slice it off the end instead of creating a `MatchData` object e.g. `"s13"[/\d+$/] #=> "13"`

Comment: The second solution is the one I'm upvoting. (The first one horrifies me :) )

Comment: Also  horrified. Ditch #1. Still need to convert #2 to an integer, allowing for the string to contain no digits (e.g., return `nil` if no digits).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I feel like #2 is up to the OP maybe 0 is acceptable as no numbers as well and the OP already stated they know how to convert to integer so I think the question is specific to extracting the numbers

Comment: Why do you capture the digits? Also I think you should use `\z` which is end of string instead of `$` which is end of line.